# I wonder how string classes in Java return strings

Tags: java

There are some string-related classes in the Java language, such as String and StringBuffer, which can be loaded with just the object's name

It's like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuffer msg = new StringBuffer("Hello JAVA");
    printMsg(msg);
}
public static void printMsg(StringBuffer msg) {
    msg.append("I like JAVA");
    System.out.println("printMsg: " + msg);
}
```

However, other classes and custom classes are not enough for the name of the object
So when you load a value, you must write:

```
public class IntReference {
    private int a;
    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a=a;
    }
    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void add(int y) {
        a+=y;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    IntReference intref = new IntReference();
    int a=10;

    intref.setA(a);     
    System.out.println(intref.getA());
    plus(intref);
    System.out.println(intref.getA());

}
public static void plus(IntReference intref) {
    intref.add(10);
    System.out.println(intref.getA());
}
```

So how do the String and StringBuffer classes get their values ​​by name alone?
What mechanism does it work with?

Comment: I don't *know*, but I assume that the string classes are special, and get some special treatment by the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass an object to the `println` method of `System.out`, what gets called is the `toString` method, declared in the `Object` class.  That's just so that `System.out.println` can figure out what to print.

The way the `toString` method is defined in `Object` isn't very helpful - it prints out a bunch of characters that generally relate to the memory location of the object, rather than its contents.

However some classes, including `StringBuffer`, have their own version of `toString` which overrides the implementation in `Object`.  So if you call `System.out.println` and pass it a `StringBuffer`, you'll actually see the content of the buffer, rather than the characters that you'd get if the version of `toString` from the `Object` class was called.

Your `IntReference` class does not have its own `toString` method, so when you pass an `IntReference` object to `System.out.println`, the `toString` method from the `Object` class gets called.  That's not very useful, which is why you're doing things like `System.out.println(intref.getA())` instead.

Comment: In addition I will provide the explicit [Object::toString documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) and a sample [how to do it](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-tostring-method-in-java/) as you post describes why is it needed.

Answer (score 0):

`String` represents fixed-length, immutable character sequences while `StringBuffer` represents growable and writable character sequences.
`StringBuffer` may have characters and substrings inserted in the middle or appended to the end. It will automatically grow to make room for such additions and often has more characters preallocated than are actually needed, to allow room for growth.

`StringBuffer(String str)`: It accepts a String argument that sets the initial contents of the StringBuffer object and reserves room for 16 more characters without reallocation.
For more basics , just see this link : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/java_lang_stringbuffer.htm